# What's the best way to implement roles/permissions to users in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, cancan, bcrypt, rolify

Disclaimer: I'm not using **Devise**, My authentication is being handled using **bcrypt**.

I want to know what are my best options, for the long run in adding roles to my users. For a while my users have been my `Company` model, and I've been holding off on creating an actual `User` model until now. My users will consist of upper level management, managers, and regular employees.

I don't know if I'm over complicating it, but I feel like dealing with this with a simple `boolean` on the `User` record is too simple. I think that's too simple because I know that there are gems that handle this like `Rolify` and `CanCan`. Can I get some advice/tips that will benefit me for the long-term.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my answers as I did not see the disclaimer before. 
Use JWT with Auth0. Below is the website to Auth0.
https://auth0.com/

Auth0 will take care of all the permission/role issues if you set it right. It is also incredibly flexible as you scale.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a new column to the user table

`add_column :users, roles, :integer, default: 0`

and for exemple on your user model

`enum role: [:contributor, :owner, :supervisor]`